# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.ValueExpressionToValueBinding

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, websphere-liberty

We have an issue with SAVE button not working throughout the application. Remaining buttons are working fine.

we have JSF 2.2, primefaces5.1 and application running on Websphere libertyprofile.

> when I click on the save button it is throwing below exception
>
> Causedby: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.ValueExpressionToValueBinding cannot be
> found by com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsf.2.2_1.0.14.cl160320160831-1555

Stack Trace:

```
[err] Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.ValueExpressionToValueBinding cannot be found by com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsf.2.2_1.0.14.cl160320160831-1555
[err]   at javax.faces.component._ClassUtils.simpleClassForName(_ClassUtils.java:169)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 77 more
[err] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.ValueExpressionToValueBinding cannot be found by com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsf.2.2_1.0.14.cl160320160831-1555
[err]   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[err]   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[err]   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
[err]   at javax.faces.component._ClassUtils.classForName(_ClassUtils.java:145)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 91 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the WebSphere jsf-2.2 feature, or are you bundling MyFaces with your webapp?

Comment: I configured <feature>jsf-2.2</feature> in Websphere Liberty server.xml <featureManager>

Comment: Have you bundled MyFaces in your application, too?  If you want to use the jsf-2.2 feature, you should remove the MyFaces jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar from your application (WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: I don't see jar in WEB-INF/lib, we are using maven. I see below entry in main pom.xml,<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
                <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${myfaces.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

Comment: Try setting the scope to `provided` for those MyFaces artifacts

Comment: hmm, it din't work

Comment: Can you update your question with the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @wtlucy updated with stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide more details? Because it seems not clear.

In most cases such stacktrace means that you haven't some library on your classpath. In your case it may be:

**Apache MyFaces JSF 2.2 Core Impl** jar

If you are using Maven to build your project. you can find appropriate jar-file here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl